# Why does bozza (draft) come from *bautan ("to push, strike")?

Tags: etymology

How is "to push, strike" related to a documentary draft? Humans do not push, or strike to write or send drafts. Or is Wiktionary wrong?

> ### [Etymology 1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bozza#Etymology_1)
>
> From [Vulgar Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgar_Latin) **bottia*, a [Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_languages) borrowing, from [Frankish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankish_language) *[*boce](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Proto-West_Germanic/boce&action=edit&redlink=1)* (“knob”), from [Old High German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_High_German) *[bozzan](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=bozzan&action=edit&redlink=1)* (“to beat”), from [Proto-West Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-West_Germanic_language) *[*bautan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-West_Germanic/bautan)* (“to push, strike”). Compare [French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_language) *[bosse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bosse#French)*, [Occitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitan_language) *[bossa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bossa#Occitan)*; also Romanian *[bot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bot#Romanian)*.
>
> Alternatively, a northern variant of Italian *[boccia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boccia#Italian)*, from a Latin root **buttia*, from [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[buttis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buttis#Latin)*.
>
> ### Noun
>
> **bozza** f (*plural* **[bozze](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bozze#Italian)**)
>
> 1. [bump](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bump)
> 2. [draft](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/draft) or [proof](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proof) (of a document)

Comment: The Treccani dictionary speaks about *\*bottia* of obscure origin as the source for the modern word.

Comment: Wiktionary isn't, in itself, a reliable source. Does it give any?